# How can I configure Visual Studio to automatically clear temporary files after a build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

Where in Visual Studio 2008 can one specify what files should be deleted after a build (for example, .obj and such)? Is there such an option?

Comment: You can put commands into the "after build" phase of your project. Why would you need to delete `*.obj` files, though? Wouldn't it make your rebuilds slower?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Actually, not me. A coleague of mine. He's used to command line compilation, and pretty much anything except the final .exe "bugs him" ;) Don't ask, long story :)

Comment: No, seriously, your colleague should get a life. (Hey, the code of conduct says we must be polite to other members; your colleague is not a member, so.)

Comment: C-:= there are very good reasons for doing things the way we do: we use IDEs, we keep the object files and the temporary files, we use not only keyboards but also mice, we use object-oriented languages, etc. Very-very good reasons for all of these. When someone refuses some of these out of pure whim, it is like saying "I am used to living in the stone age, all these modern age fads 'bug me', please let me live in the stone age".

Comment: @MikeNakis - He is one of the most productive members on our team, and a specialist in his field. The reason we use all of the above is to get the job done. He gets it done! If he doesn't want object files, for whatever reason, it's fine by me if he wants to live in the paleolithic.

Comment: C-:= OK, of course there is nothing I can say against that.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [post-build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx) that runs a batch file to do this, but I don't believe that such functionality is built in.

The reason why the object files and other temporary files are not automatically deleted upon a successful build is because Microsoft's compiler supports [incremental compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx). This allows one to build large projects much more quickly, because components that have been previously built but are still up-to-date will not have to be rebuilt.

Comment: Hi Cody, thanks for answering. Actually, I'm using Intel's compilers inside Visual Studio. Do you know of some solution that lets you "customize the build", i.e. where you can, as a set of actions, set what happens before compilation and linking, and what afterwards (like the mentioned deleting of files)? Can be an external solution as well?

Comment: @Rook: Hmm, that complicates things a bit. I don't know anything about integrating a third-party compiler into VS. It sounds like pre- and post-build events would do what you want, but as I said, I'm not sure how they'd interact with an altered configuration. (And considering that information, I may have mistagged the question by adding `msbuild`.)

Comment: No, no, not at all. Leave it just as that. I just found out a few interesting details which could prove useful in the future.

Comment: Exqueez me?  I thought that the reason why object files are not automatically deleted upon a successful build is so that on the next build they do not need to be recompiled at all unless the corresponding source files have been changed. Of course, incremental compilation takes this even one step further, but the basic reason is so that a build does not always have to be a build-all, no?

Comment: @MikeNakis - When the programs are relatively small, it doesn't make much of a difference. And when you have a lot of those in one directory, and they work in between each other, it can start to be a pain.

Comment: @Rook Yes, of course. That's why we always put them in a separate, "Project Output Folder", so that they are not in the way.